# Can someone explain how this bitMask code works?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, bit, bit-shift, bit-masks

This is code that my partner came up with but for some reason I can't get a hold of him to ask him how it's suppose to work. I've been through it many times now and can't seem to get the answer I'm suppose to get.

```
/**
 * bitMask - Generate a mask consisting of all 1's 
 *   lowbit and highbit
 *   Examples: bitMask(5,3) = 0x38
 *   Assume 0 <= lowbit <= 31, and 0 <= highbit <= 31
 *   If lowbit > highbit, then mask should be all 0's
 *   Legal ops: ! ~ & ^ | + << >>
 */
int bitMask(int highbit, int lowbit) {
   int i = ~0;
   return ~(i << highbit << 1) & (i << lowbit);
}
```

Comment: Edit your comments Ryan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function is actually incorrect: for large values of `highbit` and `lowbit`, it may have implementation specific behavior or even undefined behavior.  It should use and return `unsigned` types:

```
unsigned bitMask(int highbit, int lowbit) {
    unsigned i = ~0U;
    return ~(i << highbit << 1) & (i << lowbit);
}
```

Here are the steps:

- `i = ~0U;` sets i to all bits 1.
- `i << highbit` shifts these bits to the left, inserting `highbit` 0 bits in the low order bits.
- `i << highbit << 1` makes room for one more 0 bit.  One should not simplify this expression as `i << (highbit + 1)` because such a bit shift is implementation defined if `highbit + 1` becomes larger or equal to the number of bits in the type of `i`.
- `~(i << highbit << 1)` complements this mask, creating a mask with `highbit + 1` bits set in the low order positions and 0 for the higher bits.
- `i << lowbit` creates a mask with `lowbit` 0 bits and 1 in the higher positions.
- `~(i << highbit << 1) & (i << lowbit)` computes the intersection of these 2 masks, result has 1 bits from bit number `lowbit` to bit number `highbit` inclusive, numbering the bits from `0` for the least significant.

examples:

- `bitMask(31, 0)` -> `0xFFFFFFFF`.
- `bitMask(0, 0)` -> `0x00000001`.
- `bitMask(31, 16)` -> `0xFFFF0000`.
- `bitMask(15, 0)` -> `0x0000FFFF`.

This numbering method is used in hardware specifications.  I personally prefer a different method where one specifies the number of bits to skip and the number of bits to set, more consistent with bit-field specifications:

```
unsigned bitSpec(int start, int len) {
    return (~0U >> (32 - len)) << start;
}
```

and the same examples:

- `bitSpec(0, 32)` -> `0xFFFFFFFF`.
- `bitSpec(0, 1)` -> `0x00000001`.
- `bitSpec(16, 16)` -> `0xFFFF0000`.
- `bitSpec(0, 16)` -> `0x0000FFFF`.

Comment: why should we make room for one more zero bit in (i << highbit << 1)? Can you please explain?

Comment: @SittingBull: in your specification, `highbit` is included. One must shift `i` one more step in order for all bits upto and *including* `highbit` to be cleared so the `~` sets the all to `1` and clears any bits above `highbit`.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, given the description included with your function, the function is doing exactly what you seem to intend it to do. The primary problem is you are using `int` instead of `unsigned int`. That will cause problems with sign extension. (not to mention the lack of definition for signed shifts in C).

A simple conversion to `unsigned` will show you it is operating as you expect:

Short example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned int bitMask (unsigned int highbit, unsigned int lowbit) {
    unsigned int i = ~0;
    return ~(i << highbit << 1) & (i << lowbit);
}

char *binstr (unsigned long n, unsigned char sz, unsigned char szs, char sep) {

    static char s[128 + 1] = {0};
    char *p = s + 128;
    unsigned char i;

    for (i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        p--;
        if (i > 0 && szs > 0 && i % szs == 0)
            *p-- = sep;
        *p = (n >> i & 1) ? '1' : '0';
    }

    return p;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    unsigned high = argc > 1 ? (unsigned)strtoul (argv[1], NULL, 10) : 5;
    unsigned low  = argc > 2 ? (unsigned)strtoul (argv[2], NULL, 10) : 3;

    printf ("%s\n", binstr (bitMask (high, low), 32, 8, '-'));

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/bitmask
00000000-00000000-00000000-00111000

$ ./bin/bitmask 10 3
00000000-00000000-00000111-11111000

$ ./bin/bitmask 31 5
11111111-11111111-11111111-11100000

$ ./bin/bitmask 4 8
00000000-00000000-00000000-00000000
```

Comment: Alright, all you downvoters that lack the integrity to explain how you can downvote in the time less than required to read the post, Let's have your explanation???

Comment: It looks like you copied this answer from [a previous answer of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31199912). That's fine… except that answer is a general description of bit masks, and doesn't explain anything about the code snippet in the question.

Comment: No, the relevant parts. It is a different answer.